# JavaScript for Text Preview on Object

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where a client wants her clients to see a preview of a tag before they purchase. They can type in whatever they want to be on the tag and see a preview of it so they can get an idea of how it will look. The larger tags need to have 5 lines of text. I have 4 lines that work but need a 5th. I know there is something small that I'm overlooking. Here is what I have for code as of right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var canvasFront = document.getElementById('canvas-front'),
ctx = canvasFront.getContext('2d');
canvasFront.width = 293;
// canvas.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
canvasFront.height = 199;

ctx.drawImage($('#preview-image').get(0), 0, 0);

function firstLine(context, text) {
    context.textBaseline='middle';
    var fontsize = 75;
    context.font = "75px Arial";

    while (context.measureText(text[0]).width > 145 ) {
        fontsize--;
        context.font = fontsize + "px Arial";
        console.log(fontsize);
    }

        context.fillText(text[0],293/2,199/2 + 10);
}

$(document).on('input','.inp-f',function() {
    $('#preview-image').hide();
    $('#canvas-front').addClass('canvas-top');
    $('#canvas-back').removeClass('canvas-top');
    $('.canvas-link').eq(0).addClass('canvas-link-active');
    $('.canvas-link').eq(1).removeClass('canvas-link-active');
    var inputValues = [];
    $( ".inp-f" ).each(function( index ) {
        if ($.trim(this.value).length) {
            inputValues.push(this.value);
        }

    });

    //redraw image
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasFront.width,canvasFront.height);
    ctx.drawImage($('#preview-image').get(0), 0, 0);
    //refill text
    ctx.fillStyle = "#4b4b4b";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";


    if (inputValues.length === 1) {

        firstLine(ctx, inputValues);

    }

    if (inputValues.length === 2) {


        var fontsize = 42;

        for (i=0; i<inputValues.length; i++) {
            if (i === 0) {

                ctx.font = fontsize + "px Arial";
                while (ctx.measureText(inputValues[0]).width > 140 ) {
                    fontsize--;
                    ctx.font = fontsize + "px Arial";
                    console.log(fontsize);
                } 

                ctx.textBaseline='alphabetic';

                ctx.fillText(inputValues[0],293/2,(199/2) + 5);
            }
            if (i === 1) {
                var l2FontSize = (fontsize / 1.16) ;
                console.log(l2FontSize);
                ctx.font = l2FontSize + "px Arial";
                while (ctx.measureText(inputValues[1]).width > 140 ) {
                    l2FontSize--;
                    ctx.font = l2FontSize + "px Arial";
                    console.log(l2FontSize);
                }
                var y = 199/2 + 15;

                ctx.textBaseline='hanging';
                ctx.fillText(inputValues[1],293/2,y); 

            }
        }
    }

    if (inputValues.length === 3) {

        var fontsize = 30;
        var l2FontSize;

        for (i=0; i<inputValues.length; i++) {
            if (i === 0) {
                ctx.font = fontsize + "px Arial";
                while (ctx.measureText(inputValues[0]).width > 135 ) {
                    fontsize--;
                    ctx.font = fontsize + "px Arial";
                    console.log(fontsize);
                } 

                ctx.textBaseline='middle';

                ctx.fillText(inputValues[0],293/2,(199/3) + 20);
            }
            if (i === 1) {
                l2FontSize = (fontsize / 1.16);
                console.log(l2FontSize);
                ctx.font = l2FontSize + "px Arial";
                while (ctx.measureText(inputValues[1]).width > 135 || ctx.measureText(inputValues[2]).width > 135  ) {
                    l2FontSize--;
                    ctx.font = l2FontSize + "px Arial";
                    console.log(l2FontSize);
                }
                var y = 199/3 + 38;

                ctx.textBaseline='hanging';
                ctx.fillText(inputValues[1],293/2,y); 

            }


            if (i === 2) {
                var l3FontSize = l2FontSize;
                console.log(l3FontSize);
                ctx.font = l3FontSize + "px Arial";
                var y;
                if (inputValues[1].length > 15) {
                    y = 199/3 + 58;
                } else {
                     y = 199/3 + 60;
                }
                ctx.textBaseline='hanging';
                ctx.fillText(inputValues[2],293/2,y, 135); 

            }
        }
    }

    if (inputValues.length === 4) {

        var fontsize = 20;
        var l2FontSize;

        for (i=0; i<inputValues.length; i++) {
            if (i === 0) {
                ctx.font = fontsize + "px Arial";
                while (ctx.measureText(inputValues[0]).width > 135 || ctx.measureText(inputValues[1]).width > 135 || ctx.measureText(inputValues[2]).width > 135 ||ctx.measureText(inputValues[3]).width  > 135 ) {
                    fontsize--;
                    ctx.font = fontsize + "px Arial";
                    console.log(fontsize);
                } 

                ctx.textBaseline='middle';

                ctx.fillText(inputValues[0],293/2,(199/4 + 35));
            }
            if (i === 1) {
                l2FontSize = (fontsize / 1.16);
                // l2FontSize = fontsize;
                console.log(l2FontSize);
                ctx.font = l2FontSize + "px Arial";

                var y = 199/4 + 48;

                ctx.textBaseline='hanging';
                ctx.fillText(inputValues[1],293/2,y); 

            }


            if (i === 2) {
                var l3FontSize = l2FontSize;
                console.log(l3FontSize);
                ctx.font = l3FontSize + "px Arial";
                var y = 199/4 + 67;
                ctx.textBaseline='hanging';
                ctx.fillText(inputValues[2],293/2,y, 150); 

            }

            if (i === 3) {
                var l4FontSize = l2FontSize;
                console.log(l4FontSize);
                ctx.font = l4FontSize + "px Arial";

                var y = 199/4 + 86;

                ctx.textBaseline='hanging';
                ctx.fillText(inputValues[3],293/2,y, 150); 

            }
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Damn do you really need it to be that huge? With canvas and stuff? It could be simpler with a simple div with absolute positioning.

Comment: @Phiter unfortunately, yes. Here is a link to one of their medium tags: https://www.silverpawtags.com/product/medium-stainless-steel-bone-id-tag/. Under the "Customize Your Tag" is the inputs I need.